# Radio button group appears only when first one gives output

Tags: javascript, html

I have three radio buttons groups i want to hide the last two radio button groups which will be displayed once appropriate output from first is given.

The code:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function displaytxt(e) {
                var valueRadio = e;
                if (valueRadio == 0)
                {
                    document.getElementById('dynamictxt').style.display = 'none';
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById('dynamictxt').style.display = '';
                }
            }
 </script>
        <div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function displaytxt1(e) {
                    var valueRadio = e;
                    if (valueRadio == 2) {
                        document.getElementById("dynamictxt1").innerHTML = "Check if the termination is for past date or future date";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        document.getElementById("dynamictxt1").innerHTML = "Go back to the request manager for confirming the user termination date";
                    }
                }
            </script>
```

Is there a way to do so using java script?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To answer your question - there is. If you want more specific answer, be more specific with your code example.

Comment: The answer is, "yes". But, you have to show us your code and what attempt(s), you've made.

Comment: I have tried to use looping in order to hide the below radio buttons using the java script but no luck nothing happens.

Comment: Posting the code i used below.

Comment: @R.Kaushal You should post the code in a question not as an answer.

Comment: edit your question to post the code. You created an answer to your own questoin indeed

Comment: where are the radio buttons? where is the code to try to show/hide them?

Comment: sorry i'm new to this and having trouble in adding the code i'm using

Answer (score 0):

```
try like this
    <div id="rates">
      <input type="radio" id="r1" name="rate" value="Fixed Rate"> Fixed Rate
      <input type="radio" id="r2" name="rate" value="Variable Rate"> Variable Rate
      <input type="radio" id="r3" name="rate" value="Multi Rate" checked="checked"> Multi Rate  
    </div>
    if (document.getElementById('r1').checked) {
      rate_value = document.getElementById('r1').value;
    }
```

Comment: this is not even remotely related to what OP asked

Comment: Sathish thanks for answer but i have 3 groups of radio buttons in different <div> i want to hide the whole group until the one radio button from first group is selected.

Comment: yes u can do decarle a top level div  in event u can get all id of div once the selected div is clicked .hide the remaining div elements by id it will work  u can do like this var link = document.getElementById('nav-ask');
link.style.display = 'none'; //or

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could understand your question, but based on the title of your question, perhaps, this could help

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<p id="rad1"><input type="radio" name="rdbutton" value="radio" id="rdbutton_0">
      Radio 1</p>
 <p id="rad2"><input type="radio" name="rdbutton" value="radio" id="rdbutton_1">
      Radio 2</p>
<p id="rad3"><input type="radio" name="rdbutton" value="radio" id="rdbutton_2">
      Radio 3</p>
</form>

<script>
$('#rad1').on('click',function(){
    hideSelects();
});

function hideSelects() {
    $('p#rad2').hide();
    $('p#rad3').hide();
};
</script>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nzcage/rtvrr0xj/)